# How to simulate a USB unplug/replug after the device is safely removed?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, usb, device-driver

If I send `IOCTL_INTERNAL_USB_CYCLE_PORT` I/O request to the USB device, it works as unplug and replug. but if I safely removed it from the system tray, then send the same request, I get 0xC000000E error code, which is `STATUS_NO_SUCH_DEVICE`, and the device won't reappear. Is there a way to simulate a replug of this USB device in a "safely removed but physically connected" state?

---

From [Microsoft's USB Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff537243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The IOCTL_INTERNAL_USB_CYCLE_PORT I/O
>   request simulates a device unplug and
>   replug on the port associated with the
>   PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send IOCTL this to the [parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550630%28VS.85%29.aspx#retrieving_the_parent_of_a_device_inst) of the device - not to the device itself.